# What is the current legal/licensing status of Macross in the USA?

Tags: macross, united-states

I know of Harmony Gold's claim to own exclusive US distribution rights to all Macross related materials, such as films, toys, and print media.  I also know that Japanese courts nullified the original deal Harmony Gold had with the studio that sold them the original licensing agreement based upon the fact that they in fact did not own what they were selling (it was originally a joint Tatsunoko/Nue production).

I am wanting to know if there is any chance of Macross: Delta or F coming stateside, well, ever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regardless of what happened in Japan, if I understand correctly what this link says, Harmony Gold owns the Macross trademark at least for US and it has renewed it until 2023 as indicated near the bottom of [this Justia Trademarks page](https://trademarks.justia.com/763/82/macross-76382155.html) under **Trademark Events**

> 2013-09-05 - REGISTERED AND RENEWED (FIRST RENEWAL - 10 YRS)